# Set keybindings in a local vimrc file

Tags: vim

I have been unable to create a keybinding in a local `_vimrc` file even though I have the following settings in my global `vimrc` file:

```
set exrc            " enable per-directory vimrc files
"set secure          " disable unsafe commands in local vimrc files
```

I have local `vimrc` files for each of my workspaces, and depending on the workspace I want to be able to hit the `<F8>` key and automatically grep a string in a particular file. In my global `vimrc` file the following works fine:

```
nnoremap <F8> :grep <C-R><C-W> C:\Workspace\ProjectDirectory\subdirectory\flagsfile.h<CR>
```

But I would like to have this in a local `vimrc` file in my project root directory (`C:\workspace\ProjectDirectory`) and allow the filename to be different in each of my project directories. When I put the keymapping in the local `vimrc` file and hit `<F8>` it doesn't do anything even though I have allowed unsafe commands.

Can someone please explain the correct way to do this?

Comment: That feature only works when you start Vim from the directory that contains your local `.vimrc`, `_vimrc`, `.exrc` or `_exrc`. Is that what you do? Also, `"set secure` doesn't turn that option off, `set nosecure` does.

Comment: I launched gVim from the project directory and it is now working as expected, thanks.